# Como hacer una funcion al presionar un boton en KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin

cree una funcion llamada "hablar" entonces quiero que al presionar un boton se ejecute "hablar". Esto lo puse hacer en el activity_main.xml y funciona todo correcto. El problema viene cuando no quiero hacerlo por activity_main sino por codigo en Mainactivity.kt.

Es que luego de que se ejecute la funcion hablar quiero hacer una condicion. y no se como hacer ambas cosas al presionar el boton.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener{
hablar()
if (textView3.text=="hola") {
    textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
} else {

}
```

}

esta la funcion que hice llamada hablar:

```
fun hablar(v: View) {

        val intentActionRecognizeSpeech = Intent(
            RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
        // Configura el Lenguaje (Español-México)
        intentActionRecognizeSpeech.putExtra(
            RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "es-MX")
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intentActionRecognizeSpeech,
                RECOGNIZE_SPEECH_ACTIVITY)
        } catch (a: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                "Tú dispositivo no soporta el reconocimiento por voz",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: debes llamar la funciòn pero sin enviar como paràmetro una vista : fun hablar() {... agreguè respuesta. saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo usando la nueva API "Activity Result"

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val hablar = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
        val palabra = it.data?.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)?.get(0)
        if (palabra != null && it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            textView3.text = palabra
            if (palabra == "hola") textView.isVisible = true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
                .putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "es-MX")
            hablar.launch(intent)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola si, creo que entiendes lo que quiero hacer, crei que ese codigo que pusiste me funcionaria, pero lanzo dos errores.

quizas te ayude ver el codigo de la funcion hablar.

la pondre en el post.

Comment: Espero que esto te ayude

Answer (score 0):

Cuando mandas llamar la función desde la vista desde el layout mediante

```
android:onClick="hablar"
```

la función en código debe recibir una vista como parámetro

```
   fun hablar(v: View) {
     ...
      ...
   }
```

Si ahora deseas llamar el mètodo pero desde còdigo debes definir un listener

```
    myButton.setOnClickListener{
        hablar()
    }
```

pero en este caso tu mètodo no necesitas definir la vista como parámetro en la función `hablar()` :

```
   fun hablar() {
     ...
      ...
   }
```